# Celery worker dies on file downloading

Tags: python, docker-compose, celery

Celery worker dies immediately after staring download file via requests or urllib.
Without any errors or logs.

All server services are running in docker containers.

There should not be any permission issues because folders in download path are creating fine before download start.

There are 2 workers in system:
worker1 start command is

```
celery -A backend worker 
      -P gevent 
      -c 2
      -Q default,products
      --purge 
      --max-tasks-per-child 3000
      --without-gossip 
      --without-mingle
      --loglevel=INFO
```

worker2 start command is:

```
celery -A backend worker 
      -P gevent 
      -c 2
      -Q default,parser
      --purge 
      --max-tasks-per-child 3000
      --without-gossip 
      --without-mingle
      --loglevel=INFO
```

Server configuration is 4gb RAM, Intel Xeon Processor (Cascadelake) 2.4 GHz x4

Any advises would be appreciated.

Comment: Let’s first verify the worker can “do stuff”, including import relevant libraries. Ask a worker to append “hello world” to a text file, and view the output. Working? Good! Now see if print() to stdout gets logged. Then see if “assert False” stack trace gets logged. Then go back to debugging the requests GET issue.

Comment: Workers do stuff pretty well, there are some other tasks that work without issues

Comment: Humor me. Work through the process. You’re saying that this result is “impossible”, and I’m sympathetic, I’ve been there. Go back to verifying the basics. Keep making a “working” thing closer and closer to the celery task of interest, until you break it. Then take one step back, and tweak it some more.

Comment: That means that your download task blocks. If you remove the `-P gevent` and everything works (because in prefork mode, which is the default, for each task Celery will use a dedicated worker process) than you will know for sure.